# Deadlock (fork + malloc) libc (glibc-2.17, glibc-2.23)

Tags: c, deadlock, libc

Im running into a pretty annoying problem :
I have a program which creates one thread at the start, this thread will launch other stuff during its execution (fork() immediatly followed by execve()).

Here is the bt of both threads at the point where my program reached (I think) the deadlock :

Thread 2 (LWP 8839):

#0  0x00007ffff6cdf736 in __libc_fork () at ../sysdeps/nptl/fork.c:125

#1  0x00007ffff6c8f8c0 in _IO_new_proc_open (fp=fp@entry=0x7ffff00031d0, command=command@entry=0x7ffff6c26e20 "ps -u brejon | grep \"cvc\"

#2  0x00007ffff6c8fbcc in _IO_new_popen (command=0x7ffff6c26e20 "ps -u `user` | grep \"cvc\" | wc -l", mode=0x42c7fd "r") at iopopen.c:296

#3-4 ...

#5  0x00007ffff74d9434 in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff6c27700) at pthread_create.c:333

#6  0x00007ffff6d0fcfd in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:109

Thread 1 (LWP 8835):

#0  __lll_lock_wait_private () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:95

#1  0x00007ffff6ca0ad9 in malloc_atfork (sz=140737337120848, caller=) at arena.c:179

#2  0x00007ffff6c8d875 in __GI__IO_file_doallocate (fp=0x17a72230) at filedoalloc.c:127

#3  0x00007ffff6c9a964 in __GI__IO_doallocbuf (fp=fp@entry=0x17a72230) at genops.c:398

#4  0x00007ffff6c99de8 in _IO_new_file_overflow (f=0x17a72230, ch=-1) at fileops.c:820

#5  0x00007ffff6c98f8a in _IO_new_file_xsputn (f=0x17a72230, data=0x17a16420, n=682) at fileops.c:1331

#6  0x00007ffff6c6fcb2 in _IO_vfprintf_internal (s=0x17a72230, format=, ap=ap@entry=0x7fffffffcf18) at vfprintf.c:1632

#7  0x00007ffff6c76a97 in __fprintf (stream=, format=) at fprintf.c:32

#8-11 ...

#12 0x000000000042706e in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffd698, envp=0x7fffffffd6b8) at mains/ignore/.c:146

Both stays stuck here forever with both glibc-2.17 and glibc-2.23

Any help is welcomed :'D

EDIT :

Here is a minimal example :

```
  1 #include <stdlib.h>
  2 #include <pthread.h>
  3 #include <unistd.h>
  4 
  5 void * thread_handler(void * args)
  6 {
  7         char * argv[] = { "/usr/bin/ls" };
  8         char * newargv[] = { "/usr/bin/ls", NULL };
  9         char * newenviron[] = { NULL };
 10         while (1) {
 11                 if (vfork() == 0) {
 12                         execve(argv[0], newargv, newenviron);
 13                 }
 14         }
 15 
 16         return 0;
 17 }
 18 
 19 int main(void)
 20 {
 21         pthread_t thread;
 22         pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_handler, NULL);
 23 
 24         int * dummy_alloc;
 25 
 26         while (1) {
 27                 dummy_alloc = malloc(sizeof(int));
 28                 free(dummy_alloc);
 29         }
 30 
 31         return 0;
 32 }
```

Environment :
user:deadlock$ cat /etc/redhat-release

Scientific Linux release 7.3 (Nitrogen)

user:deadlock$ ldd --version

ldd (GNU libc) 2.17

EDIT 2 :
The rpm package version is : glibc-2.17-196.el7.x86_64

<s>I can not get the line numbers using the rpm package. Here is the BT using the glibc given with the distribution :</s> solved with debuginfo.

(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7ffff77fb700 (LWP 59753)):

#0  vfork () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/vfork.S:44

#1  0x000000000040074e in thread_handler (args=0x0) at deadlock.c:11

#2  0x00007ffff7bc6e25 in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff77fb700) at pthread_create.c:308

#3  0x00007ffff78f434d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:113

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7ffff7fba740 (LWP 59746)):

#0  0x00007ffff7878226 in _int_free (av=0x7ffff7bb8760 , p=0x602240, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3927

#1  0x00000000004007aa in main () at deadlock.c:28

Comment: Can you post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Hi, calling fork in a multithreaded programs would lead problems, when called in thread it copies entire address space but doesn't clone any thread, other than the thread which called it. Which would lead to permanent resource lock. This behaviour is defined in POSIX.

Comment: Your original code uses `fork`, but your example uses `vfork`, so it's not representative. What's your environment? I wonder on which lock, exactly, `__libc_fork` is blocking (i.e., what is on line 125?). Are there only two threads?  Anything using C++ streams?  Or calling `fflush (NULL)`? We have certainly fixed some bugs in this area over the years.

Comment: I read that calling fork in a multithreaded program will copy only the calling thread in the child process, i'm totally fine with this behaviour. And as you can see in the minimal example I don't call any function between fork() and execve().

Comment: @FlorianWeimer It happens with fork() too.
Mine environment It a Scientific Linux 7.3.
On line 125 : a call to this macro :
     24 #define ARCH_FORK() \
     25   INLINE_SYSCALL (clone, 4,                                                   \
     26                   CLONE_CHILD_SETTID | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID | SIGCHLD, 0,     \
     27                   NULL, &THREAD_SELF->tid)
No, only two threads.
And only C code.

Comment: @bob, what about my other questions? Please also add the exact glibc RPM version to your post.

Comment: @bob, I doubt that the posted backtrace is from a Scientific Linux 7.3 environment. Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 at least does not have the `nptl/sysdeps` cleanup, so it does not have the `sysdeps/nptl/fork.c` file. You really need to provide accurate information about your environment, so that we can make sense of the backtrace.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer, This is a libc I compiled myself, I can't guaranteed that it has been done flawlesssly.
But its a Scientific Linux 7.3 : cat /etc/redhat-release Scientific Linux release 7.3 (Nitrogen)

Comment: @NishanthShetty *Hi, calling fork in a multithreaded programs would lead problems, when called in thread it copies entire address space but doesn't clone any thread, other than the thread which called it. Which would lead to permanent resource lock. This behaviour is defined in POSIX* POSIX defines `fork()` as async-signal-safe, which is much more stringent than merely multithread-safe.  This is not a POSIX problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a custom-compiled glibc.  It is possible that something went wrong with the installation.  Note that [Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4 backports a fix for a deadlock between malloc and fork](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=906468), and you are missing that because you compiled your own glibc.  The [fix for the upstream bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=19431) went only into upstream version 2.24, so if you are basing your custom build on that, you may not have this fix.  (Although the backtrace would look differently for that one.)

I think we fixed at least another post-2.17 libio-related deadlock bug.

**EDIT** I have been dealing with fork-related deadlocks for too long.  There are multiple issues with the reproducer as posted:

- There is no `waitpid` call for the PID.  As a result, the process table will be quickly filled with zombies.
- No error checking for `execve`.  If the `/usr/bin/ls` pathname does not exist (for example, on a system which did not undergo [UsrMove](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/UsrMove)), `execve` will return, and the next iteration of the loop will launch *another* `vfork` call.

I fixed both issues (because debugging what is approaching a fork bomb is not fun at all), but I can't reproduce a hang with glibc-2.17-196.el7.x86_64.

Comment: The deadlock happens with the libc(2.17) given with the distribution(7.3) too, so the I should have the backported fix in it (which is not a fix for the bug I got if this is the case).
I'll try a 2.24.

Comment: Please post the backtrace with the line numbers from the distribution package, and the exact RPM package version, so that we can match the backtrace with the source code.

Comment: I edited the first post with these informations, but could not get the line numbers for the libc's distribution.

Comment: Please try to install the `debuginfo` packages—first install `yum-utils`, and then run `debuginfo-install glibc`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you can find the backtrace updated with the line numbers in the first post.

Comment: Thanks, I've since realized that the posted reproducer has problems of its own, so it does not really show a glibc bug.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the bug, after fixing the reproducer with @FlorianWeimer suggestions.
Thanks for your time... I guess I was just writing bad code...